What are the minimum permissions I need to have in IAM to allow file upload using multer?
Hi I am trying to set up IAM to allow my application to follow the security guidelines of minium permissions possible in case "Knock on wood forest what ever" a bad actor gains access. I know making sure my code is secure is the first thing but again I want to be safe rather then sorry.
I need to know the different policies you would recommend to allow read access for one IAM user and write permission for another. Do I need anything more then the 'PutObject' for write and the 'GetObject' for read. I will also need to show what files a user might have stored in their own folder in S3.
Any help would be amazing.

It will depend on which API requests multer makes. It might, for example, need to call ListObjects on the bucket. I don't know that it does; I'm just saying that it might. You should read the multer documentation to understand how it expects you to configure IAM policies.

You would need to allow some permission on the bucket and object level.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/<folder>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

*Object wildcard would allow API such as PutObject, GetObject
Adjust the list of API allowed based on your specific use case.
More examples
